# Как подсчитать размер файла bmp?

Tags: bmp

Скажите, правильно ли я выполнил задание?

> Дано 65536 цветное изображение файла типа bmp размером 1920x1080, найти размер файла.

значит глубина цвета 16 бит = 2байта;
2073600 - число точек, (2073600 * 2)/1024=40573 кбайта, правильно ли я сделал?

Comment: Нет такого понятия, как "емкость файла". Если речь о размере файла BMP, то надо еще добавить заголовок, стандартный - 56 байт если мне не изменяет память.

Comment: да, размер файла, имелся ввиду. так правилбноясделал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не правильно, считать надо лучше: `(2073600 × 2) / 1024 = 4050`

В остальном все верно.

Comment: спасибо, буду повнемательнее